# Enum class member with interface cannot find methods internally

Tags: java, interface, enums

I'm having a strange issue which I'm not sure if it's a compiler problem or my understanding of enums with interfaces. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12, building an Android project, and I have a class like this:

```
public class ClassWithEnum {
    private MyEnum myEnum;

    //Trying to access it internally here throws the error
    public boolean isActionable() {
        return myEnum.isActionable();
    }

    public enum MyEnum implements Action {
        ACTIONABLE() {
            @Override
            public boolean isActionable() { return true; }
        },
        NOT_ACTIONABLE() {
            @Override
            public boolean isActionable() { return false; }
        }
    }

    public interface Action {
        public boolean isActionable();
    }
}
```

Now, this was working initially, but now the compiler is complaining (and I've tried this in a brand new project as well with the same results) with the error:

```
java: /Users/kcoppock/Documents/Projects/EnumInterfaceTest/src/com/example/EnumInterfaceTest/ClassWithEnum.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method isActionable()
location: class com.example.EnumInterfaceTest.ClassWithEnum.MyEnum
```

I've done this before (enumerations with behaviors defined by an interface) with no issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: It compile fine here. Which compiler and Java version are you using?

Comment: Same here, i did throw it in my eclipse... works fine

Comment: @JBNizet Hmm, okay, well I'm using the compiler in IntelliJ, and Java v1.6 (max for Android projects). How could I determine what compiler it's using?

Comment: Just looked, it says it's using `javac`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to implement `isActionable()` method in `MyEnum` itself. Because the method `isActionable()` defined inside the `ACIONABLE` and `NOT_ACTIONABLE` are local to them . So you need the global method for the `MyEnum` `enum` .

use this code instead:

```
public enum MyEnum implements Action {
        ACTIONABLE() {
            @Override
            public boolean isActionable() { return true; }
        },
        NOT_ACTIONABLE() {
            @Override
            public boolean isActionable() { return false; }
        };
        @Override
        public boolean isActionable() { return false;}
    }
```

Comment: This seems reasonable, and it was something I considered, but I don't believe it's actually necessary provided the enumerations actually implement the interface. Changing the compiler to Eclipse then back to javac cleared the issues and it runs with no issues.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong, it just wasn't recompiling after the change to Eclipse. It still fails without adding the global override. After adding that, it's able to compile as expected.

Comment: Yes it did. Adding the global method as you suggested causes the compiler to succeed. I'm curious if it's actually a javac bug, or just a more strict requirement in that version.

Comment: What makes you think it to be a java bug?? ACTIONABLE is like an object which is member of MyEnum class . Literally it is equivalent to `public static final MyEnum ACTIONABLE = new MyEnum(){ @Override public boolean isActionable(){return true;}; ` So untill and unless MyEnum implements isActionable() method , this method will be considered as local for ACTIONABLE object. You can't even access this method using the ACTIONABLE object itself if this method is not implemented by MyEnum itself.

Comment: A `javac` bug, not a java bug. The fact that it compiles and runs fine under one version of the compiler, but not another, implies either a bug or change of requirements. If it were not actually overriding the interface method (since it includes the annotation @Override) the compiler would complain that it is not actually overriding a superclass method. Since it's not complaining, I assume that it is in fact accessible from the local object.

Comment: yes got a point ... Can u tell me under which version of compiler is it compiling fine?

Comment: It compiles fine with the `Eclipse` compiler, or as @JBNizet mentions below, with `javac` 1.7.

Comment: Ok..Thanks i would go look for them. :)

Comment: Great answer. I would point out you can also keep the method abstract and not implement its body in the interface:

Answer (score 3):

You could try this alternative:

```
   public enum MyEnum implements Action {
        ACTIONABLE(true), 
        NOT_ACTIONABLE(false);

        private final boolean actionable;

        MyEnum(boolean actionable) {
           this.actionable = actionable;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isActionable() { 
           return this.actionable; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a workable solution too. Unfortunately the real class I'm using it with has some more complex functionality with it, but still good info. :)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a javac bug. javac compiles it fine in JDK7. It doesn't in JDK6 (javac 1.6.0_24), both from IntelliJ and from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that javac for 1.6 requires a global override for the interface method, whereas later versions do not, nor does the Eclipse compiler.

<s>Seems it was just a bug with `IntelliJ`. I changed the compiler setting from `javac` to `Eclipse`, then back to `javac` and it compiles and runs as expected.</s>

False alarm. :)

Comment: It's a javac bug in fact. EVen from the command line, javac doesn't compile it.

Comment: @JBNizet Interesting, so you can reproduce it too? It's working for me with the javac compiler now, though, after changing. Let me try to fully recompile and see if it fails.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it. Even if the Action interface and the Enum are promoted to top-level classes, it doesn't compile.

Comment: It appears both you and @VishalK are correct. If I rebuild with javac, it fails again. If I rebuild with Eclipse it compiles. If I add the default action as Vishal suggests, it compiles with javac.

Answer (score 1):

Some people already answered this perfectly, I just add one more little tip: you can also keep the method abstract in the interface:

```
public enum MyEnum implements Action {
    ACTIONABLE() {
        @Override
        public boolean isActionable() { return true; }
    },
    NOT_ACTIONABLE() {
        @Override
        public boolean isActionable() { return false; }
    };
    @Override
    abstract public boolean isActionable();
}
```